# $.post from a function does not call success function only on iPhone

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

The code below works perfectly on desktops and android phones but on iPhone using either safari or chrome, the beforesend function fires successfully, the form is posted successfully to the server but the success function never fires.

SubmitForm is called from a button onclick. I have also tried attaching an event listener using JQuery and it does exactly the same thing.

```
    function SubmitForm() {
        var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));

        $.post({
            url: raisePostUrl,
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                AddCog('SubmitBtnO', ' Processing...');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                RestoreElementShowAlert('SubmitBtnO', 'Submit', 'MsgDiv', xhr);
            },
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                ActionSuccess(result);
            },
        });
    }

    function ActionSuccess(data) {

        HideModal();

        $('#AlertDiv').html(data);

        showAlert();
    }
```

Edit: Just wanted to add that other $.post ajax requests are working on iPhone, the distinguishing differences between this request and the ones that are working are:
1. This request includes FormData
2. The function is called from a modal window on click of a button.

I have $.post requests that are called from the cshtml page without form data and they work perfectly on the iPhone. 
I also have ajax.beginform requests that are posted from modal windows that also work perfectly on the iPhone

Comment: Try `$.ajax` with `type:"post"`

Comment: "the success function never fires"...doesn't the "error" callback fire instead?

Comment: @ADyson No. the error callback does not fire...

Comment: @elegant-user complete would also affect the error handling which is not appropriate

Comment: @AliSheikhpour isn't $.post supposed to be the same thing as $.ajax with type:"post"? Anyway for the sake of trying, I will try and get back. Who knows :)

Comment: @AliSheikhpour why, exactly? $.post() is just a shorthand to automatically make a POST request. What benefit do you think your suggested change would bring?

Comment: @elegant-user that would just make it harder to distinguish between successful and failed requests. Assuming it even works, it's masking the problem, not fixing it.

Comment: @EnochOlaoye Unfortunately I don't know much about testing on iOS devices but can you run your code in some sort of emulator, or developer mode where you can see the same sort of Dev Tools info as you would get on a desktop browser? Then you can watch the request and the console and see if there are any other problems. Since it appears to be O/S- or even device-specific it seems like you need to debug on the particular device if you can.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour For the sake of trying anything, I have tried the $.ajax and it does exactly the same thing

Comment: @ADyson I thought that maybe iOS is adding something to the response that is causing jquery to misinterpret it. So I specified the response datatype as html with (dataType: "html"). Now I notice the following: If I wait for about 5 minutes, the error callback is fired with an empty xhr, a status of "error" and nothing in the errorThrown parameter. Also it appears that the request is no more getting to the server!

Comment: @ADyson It appears that the entire ajax request is timing out! setting (async: false) makes the error returned to be Timeout. As far as I know I am not doing a CORS, and the ajax request works on other platforms apart from iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that Mobile Safari may not support FormData according to the compatibility table on the Mozilla site. (Compatibility is unknown).

[FormData documentation on Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

The solution then is to use iframe fallbacks via the malsup JQuery Forms Plugin as shown below:

```
        var options = {
            type: "POST",
            url: raisePostUrl,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                AddCog('SubmitBtnO', ' Processing...');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                RestoreElementShowAlert('SubmitBtnO', 'Submit', 'MsgDiv', xhr);
            },
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                ActionSuccess(result);
            }
        };

        // pass options to ajaxForm (malsup jquery.form.js)
        $('#RaiseForm').ajaxForm(options);
```

It works perfectly on all platforms including iOS.

[Malsup Jquery Forms Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)